# C++ code help for C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers

I came across this code but not sure how I can write it in C#:

```
bool getBestFitPlane(unsigned int vcount,
                     const float *points,
                     unsigned int vstride,
                     const float *weights,
                     unsigned int wstride,
                     float *plane)
{
  bool ret = false;

  SinglePrecision::Vec3 kOrigin(0,0,0);

  float wtotal = 0;

  if ( 1 )
  {
    const char *source  = (const char *) points;
    const char *wsource = (const char *) weights;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<vcount; i++)
    {

      const float *p = (const float *) source;

      float w = 1;

      if ( wsource )
      {
        const float *ws = (const float *) wsource;
        w = *ws; //
        wsource+=wstride;
      }

      kOrigin.x+=p[0]*w;
      kOrigin.y+=p[1]*w;
      kOrigin.z+=p[2]*w;

      wtotal+=w;

      source+=vstride;
    }
  }

  float recip = 1.0f / wtotal; // reciprocol of total weighting

  kOrigin.x*=recip;
  kOrigin.y*=recip;
  kOrigin.z*=recip;


  float fSumXX=0;
  float fSumXY=0;
  float fSumXZ=0;

  float fSumYY=0;
  float fSumYZ=0;
  float fSumZZ=0;


  if ( 1 )
  {
    const char *source  = (const char *) points;
    const char *wsource = (const char *) weights;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<vcount; i++)
    {

      const float *p = (const float *) source;

      float w = 1;

      if ( wsource )
      {
        const float *ws = (const float *) wsource;
        w = *ws; //
        wsource+=wstride;
      }

      SinglePrecision::Vec3 kDiff;

      kDiff.x = w*(p[0] - kOrigin.x); // apply vertex weighting!
      kDiff.y = w*(p[1] - kOrigin.y);
      kDiff.z = w*(p[2] - kOrigin.z);

      fSumXX+= kDiff.x * kDiff.x; // sume of the squares of the differences.
      fSumXY+= kDiff.x * kDiff.y; // sume of the squares of the differences.
      fSumXZ+= kDiff.x * kDiff.z; // sume of the squares of the differences.

      fSumYY+= kDiff.y * kDiff.y;
      fSumYZ+= kDiff.y * kDiff.z;
      fSumZZ+= kDiff.z * kDiff.z;


      source+=vstride;
    }
  }

  fSumXX *= recip;
  fSumXY *= recip;
  fSumXZ *= recip;
  fSumYY *= recip;
  fSumYZ *= recip;
  fSumZZ *= recip;

  // setup the eigensolver
  SinglePrecision::Eigen kES;

  kES.mElement[0][0] = fSumXX;
  kES.mElement[0][1] = fSumXY;
  kES.mElement[0][2] = fSumXZ;

  kES.mElement[1][0] = fSumXY;
  kES.mElement[1][1] = fSumYY;
  kES.mElement[1][2] = fSumYZ;

  kES.mElement[2][0] = fSumXZ;
  kES.mElement[2][1] = fSumYZ;
  kES.mElement[2][2] = fSumZZ;

  // compute eigenstuff, smallest eigenvalue is in last position
  kES.DecrSortEigenStuff();

  SinglePrecision::Vec3 kNormal;

  kNormal.x = kES.mElement[0][2];
  kNormal.y = kES.mElement[1][2];
  kNormal.z = kES.mElement[2][2];

  // the minimum energy
  plane[0] = kNormal.x;
  plane[1] = kNormal.y;
  plane[2] = kNormal.z;

  plane[3] = 0 - kNormal.dot(kOrigin);

  return ret;
}
```

I mainly don't understand the const char line. Is it trying to get the first item of values array?

Comment: That looks like C code. Currently its not doing anything since the value of p is never used.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that in C#.  Find out what the intent is, and write it in a clean modern style.

Comment: As it is that thing is nonsensical even in C, you should either provide more context or explain what is the intent of that code.

Comment: p is used in the code, I didn't include it because I am not exactly sure what it is. @BenVoigt, I am not gonna do it in C# verbatim, but need to do the same looping operation. I am not sure what chars have to do with floats in the code.

Comment: theres no way to know what the appropriate conversion would be without knowing why the code is performing such a cast. we need more context

Comment: I added the relevant bit. Is it clear now?

Comment: That is the most retarded and useless cast I have seen in a while. As a 13k user, you should know how to post complete code. You are missing a curly brace.

Comment: `numValues` is coming from outside of the function, defining the number of elements. As the others have pointed out it's pointless. `p` is really just `values`. I don't know if you've left out code, but there is no point to having `source`, nor is there a point to having `p` in the above code. I expect that `values` is being accessed as an array of `float`s after it is being pointlessly used from a different reference.

Comment: Ok posted the complete function. I just don't want people see a huge function and leave.

Comment: The new code still does not make any sense. The loop does nothing and `const float *p = (const float *) source;` is never used. Furthermore there is no explanation for `p`, `numValues` or `origin`.

Comment: I think you should delete the question to save face. This thing's going no where...

Comment: This's the whole function though.

Comment: Also guys the author of this code might not necessarily the best programmer. Why assume it should be very good?

Comment: It doesn't need to be _very_ good, but if you're expecting people with zero context to translate it to a different language for you, it should at least be _complete_ and comprehensible.

Comment: Yes but people are still saying those lines don't make any sense.

Comment: And they're right -- they do nothing, so how should we translate "do nothing" to an arbitrary language? There are **infinite** ways to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mainly don't understand the const char line. Is it trying to get the first item of values array?

The purpose of casting `points` to `source` is to get a constant byte array (effectively) version of the `float` array that

```
// use points as a byte array
const char *source  = (const char *) points;

for (unsigned int i=0; i<vcount; i++)
{
  // get a reference to the current position in the source array
  const float *p = (const float *) source;

  ...

  // iterate to the next series of points
  source+=vstride;
}
```

I assume that `vstride` is a value of 12 or more. `vstride` is being used to skip an arbitrary number of bytes for the current point in order to calculate the weighted value. As there are at least 3 `float` points per position, that is how I came up with at least 12 (3 times 4). It could be more if there is other data in the array along with the point, between the z coordinate and the start of the next point.

The reason that it is necessary to use the `source` pointer is because pointer arithmetic works based on the `sizeof` the pointed data. Thus `(points + 12)` is different from `(source + 12)`, and clearly `vstride` is associated with the number of bytes to skip (sort of implying that the `points` reference may actually be a `struct`ure that is being used as `float` array out of convenience, which is not unusual in C/C++).

In C#, you would not be writing something like this. You are going to pass in an array/collection of Points, which is going to be an object that has an X, Y, and Z `float`ing point coordinate. Similarly, there will be an optional (can be `null`, as noted by `if (wsource)`) array/collection of Weights, which contains a single `float` value in it representing the weight for the current coordinate. It may make sense to combine them together. The points and weights have the same number of elements, if `weights` is defined.

You will not need the `vcount`, `vstride`, or `wstride` variables in C#. You can loop through the `Points` array/collection and apply the weight if any Weights are supplied.

```
float weight = 1.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; ++i)
{
    if (weights != null)
    {
        weight = weights[i].Weight;
    }

    x += points[i].X * weight;
    y += points[i].Y * weight;
    z += points[i].Z * weight;

    wtotal += weight;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, yes - although there's some strange type-casting going on here that seems unnecessary, at least given the code fragment you've posted.

The line is declaring a constant (i.e. unchangeable) pointer (*) to a char (signed byte) named 'source', and assigning it the address of the start of 'values'.  This is odd, because as you can see from the argument list, values is a const float * type.

Pointer types are often used for handling arrays in older C/C++ programs, as they are somewhat interchangeable.

For C#, you would use the built-in array type instead.

[EDIT]  Now that you've posted more source, it's clear that this was done so that they can use the 'source' variable to point into a block of floats, and increments it by a 'stride' amount of bytes (chars) when necessary to move to the float to be processed.  You can certainly devise C# code to handle this memory layout if needed (System.IntPtr might be helpful to you.)

Comment: So essentially, source is an index, right? (that he increments)

Comment: Thanks but why not just loop through the `values` using a simple for loop?

Comment: Yes - it appears that the floats are separated by some 'vstride' amount specified in bytes, which is why the odd casting is done.  If you need to operate on the same layout of data, I'd suggest getting the C fragment working in a test program with some sample data (which you can then use to confirm your C# implementation is working)

Comment: No I don't need the same memory layout, just need to do the same thing, so I will just use a simple for loop in C#.

Comment: Re q #2 - because the float values are not in a simple array, but are vstride or wstride bytes apart from each other.